# How to make $http.get request from within directive controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS directive called product. I need an action to happen whenever I click on a button that's a part of this directive that involves making an $http.get request to my server and doing work on the response. I have a file that appears to work fine until it actually gets around to making the request, at which point, the url shown in Fiddler doesn't match what I'm attempting to make the request and I'm unsure as to why.

The request, as you can see below, should be hitting my domain/api/product/GetToken api service, but in Fiddler, I show this to be going to "/user/[object%20Object]" instead and I'm unsure as to why this is. Also, the console yields no errors.

The following is the directive in question:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('product', function($location) {
 return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
    scope: {},
    controller: function($scope, $state, $cookieStore, $http) {
     $scope.productClick = function(key) {
      var url = 'http://exampleurl.com/api/product/GetToken';
      $http.get({url:url})
       .success(d, s, h, c) {
        $state.go('this.someplace');
      }
       .error(function(d, s, h, c) {
        $state.go('this.otherview');
       });
     },
     link: function($scope, e, a, m) {
      $scope.name = a.name + "123";
     }
    }
 }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea for what I can do that I'm not catching here?

Comment: Try  `$http.get(url)`

Comment: Alternatively, $http({url:url, method:'GET', params: {x:'x',y:'y'}), which takes a configuration object.

Comment: You should NOT call $http from any controller. $http always should belong in a service.

Comment: Thanks Chandermani. I upvoted yours as that resolved the problem and marked Erik's response as the answer as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using $http and $http.get differs somewhat. With just $http you do as you have written (send a config object), but with $http.get (or post, etc), you pass the url as a string. So it is:

```
$http.get('/my/url/').success(...).error(...);
```

or

```
$http.post('/my/url/', dataObject).success(...).error(...);
```

or with just $http

```
$http({url: '/my/url', method: 'GET'}).success(...).error(...);
```

Comment: Which Chandermani already said I realize now that I see his comment :P